# Do we need a fullscreen tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just noticed that [fullscreen](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fullscreen) exists.

I don't think it's a harmful tag, but not a very useful (not too used either, 10 questions as of writing) one either.

Should we keep it around?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think the tag should go away.

I think that the problem domains of "dealing with fullscreen switches" and "handling 'borderless fullscreen'" and similar are reasonable and on-topic for a game development site. It's possible we should clarify the scope of the tag though.